# Widgets in Gridview lose state when off-screen

Tags: android, gridview, dart, flutter

I'm just starting to play around with Flutter/Dart, and I'm wondering why my `Card` widgets are losing their state when they scroll offscreen.

`_isSelected` is toggled by a user tapping one one of the `Card` widgets. All is fine, until they disappear off screen - at which point they revert to normal. I'm assuming I have to take additional steps to preserve state but I'm not quite sure how to best go about this.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class CardHolder extends StatefulWidget {
  CardHolder({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CardHolderState createState() => new _CardHolderState();
}

class _CardHolderState extends State<CardHolder> {
  List _cardData;

  _getCards() async {
    String endpoint = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
    var httpClient = createHttpClient();
    var response = await httpClient.read(endpoint);

    List data = JSON.decode(response);

    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _cardData = data;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _getCards();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new GridView.extent(
        maxCrossAxisExtent: 250.0,
        mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
        crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
        children: _buildGridList(_cardData)
      );
  }
}

List<Card> _buildGridList(data) {
  if (data == null) return [];
  List<Card> cards = [];
  for (var card in data) {
    cards.add(new Card(title: card['title']));
  }
  return cards;
}

class Card extends StatefulWidget {
  Card({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  CardState createState() => new CardState();
}

class CardState extends State<Card> {

  String title;
  bool _isSelected = false;

  _toggleSelected() {
    setState(() {
      _isSelected = !_isSelected;
      print('Toggled to ' + _isSelected.toString());
    });
  }

  CardState({this.title = "No Title!"});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Rendering card: ' + widget.title);
    return new GestureDetector(
        onTap: _toggleSelected,
        child: new Container(
            constraints: new BoxConstraints(minHeight: 120.0, minWidth: 100.0, maxWidth: 100.0),
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: _isSelected ? Colors.red : Colors.white,
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(2.5)),
                boxShadow: [new BoxShadow(color: Colors.black45, blurRadius: 5.0, spreadRadius: 0.0, offset: new Offset(0.0, 3.0))]
            ),
            margin: new EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: new Text(widget.title, style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black))
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is working as intended in the sense that Flutter is designed to clean up your offscreen `State`. You can get the behavior you want by maintaining the `isSelected` boolean at a higher level of the tree, e.g. in `CardHolder` or in a model class. For simple cases a `ValueNotifier` may be sufficient. Here's an example of that.

```
import 'dart:collection';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        primaryColorBrightness: Brightness.light,
      ),
      home: new CardHolder(),
    );
  }
}

class CardHolder extends StatefulWidget {
  CardHolder({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CardHolderState createState() => new _CardHolderState();
}

class _CardHolderState extends State<CardHolder> {
  List _cardData;

  _getCards() async {
    String endpoint = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
    var httpClient = createHttpClient();
    var response = await httpClient.read(endpoint);

    List data = JSON.decode(response);

    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _cardData = data;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _getCards();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new GridView.extent(
      maxCrossAxisExtent: 250.0,
      mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
      crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
      children: _buildGridList(_cardData)
    );
  }
}

List<Card> _buildGridList(data) {
  if (data == null) return [];
  List<Card> cards = [];
  for (var card in data) {
    cards.add(new Card(
      title: card['title'],
      isSelected: new ValueNotifier<bool>(false),
    ));
  }
  return cards;
}

class Card extends AnimatedWidget {
  Card({Key key, this.title, this.isSelected }) : super(key: key, listenable: isSelected);

  final String title;
  final ValueNotifier<bool> isSelected;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Rendering card: ' + title);
    return new GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        isSelected.value = !isSelected.value;
      },
      child: new Container(
        constraints: new BoxConstraints(minHeight: 120.0, minWidth: 100.0, maxWidth: 100.0),
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          color: isSelected.value ? Colors.red : Colors.white,
          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(2.5)),
          boxShadow: [new BoxShadow(color: Colors.black45, blurRadius: 5.0, spreadRadius: 0.0, offset: new Offset(0.0, 3.0))]
        ),
        margin: new EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: new Text(title, style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black))
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I figured that had something to do with it. A quick follow-up: Why did you change the Card widget into an `AnimatedWidget` instead of a `StatefulWidget`?

Comment: Because it needs to listen for changes to the `ValueNotifier` and rebuild itself. `AnimatedWidget` does that for you automatically.

Comment: Good stuff. As opposed to calling `setState`? Assuming I wanted to extend this beyond the simple use case above, what does that pattern look like?

Comment: You should do the first thing I suggested (maintaining the selectedness of the cards at a higher level of the tree, i.e. CardHolder). Presumably you're going to need to be able to find out what cards are selected anyway when the user tries to move on to the next step of your app, so this isn't adding complexity.